# Visualisation seems weird

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f33b3ad00a86590266c7c4fd6cfa92e5)

This should be the Topographic Position Index

Pls run the Code and Zoom in and out

you will notice that the representation changes for different zoom levels, also Values from the Inspector Change
[image]
[image]
[image]

seeking for clearence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Earth Engine visualization changes with zoom level. It does not influence your calculations where you can specify the scale (e.g. reduceRegion). If you want the image to be displayed at a specific scale, use reproject. But only do this for displaying, if you are using the image for further calculations, specify the scale only afterwards.

```
var TPI30_120 = Elevation.subtract(focalmean30_120).reproject(elevation.projection(), null, 120)
```